# git error "failed to push some refs to" when accessing windows share

Tags: git, git-push, cifs

When I try to push my repo to a mounted windows share I got the following error message:

```
git push
Counting objects: 47, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25/25), 508.09 KiB | 88 KiB/s, done.
Total 25 (delta 18), reused 13 (delta 7)
fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Host is down
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To /dir/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to /dir/
```

I tried a lot of things which I found on other posts but they didn't work for me:

```
git gc
git repack
git config --add core.sharedRepository group
```

I also changed the file permissions:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc 156 Sep 30 14:51 config
-rwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc  73 Apr 20  2012 description
-rwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc  23 Apr 20  2012 HEAD
drwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc   0 Apr 20  2012 hooks
drwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc   0 Apr 20  2012 info
drwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc   0 Sep 24 16:26 objects
drwxrwxrwx 0 marc marc   0 Apr 20  2012 refs
```

and there is also enough space left on the drive.

Comment: to pin down the error: have you tried to push to another local folder (that is not a remote mount)? does that work? if that works and the problem is (probably) related to the mounted share, describe the share in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this error is caused by the git version which is in the standard apt repositiories from Ubuntu 12.4 LTS. After installing a newer version from another repo it works

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```